# How can I compare 2 excel file unique rows by price in UIPath?

Tags: excel, uipath, uipath-studio

I am scraping online shops, writing down the data in separate excel files for each shop (product name, shop url, product url, and price). I want to check if there are same products in 2 excel files(like IPhone 14 pro max on amazon and IPhone 14 pro max on ebay), compare their price, and write down the lower price product(product name, shop url, product url and price) to another excel file(like lowest price products). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Read both Excel files
2. Use the [Join Data Tables](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/join-data-tables) to merge them by the column that contains the product ID (needs to be unique for sure)
3. Join Type `Inner` should work
4. And now you get the both prices

You could also use pure LINQ, [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSWT5qSBiHg).

At the end it depends on the result you need. So either filter columns or use some advanced comparisons to get Amazon or Ebay as cheapest. But what happens when both have same price? So make sure you also test this one.